# How do I configure scoped filters to work the same for consumers as for activities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, masstransit

I have managed to configure scoped services together with scoped filters for consumers, meaning that I can set a value to a scoped service in a filter implementing `IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>` and registering the filter with `UseConsumeFilter`. The filter sets a value in my scoped service and after that the scoped service can be injected into my consumer and still have the value set.

I have tried to do the same thing for activities using `IFilter<ExecuteContext<TArguments>>` and registering my filter with `UseExecuteActivityFilter`.

The values set in the ExecuteActivityContext are not reachable in the Activity. I think they become two different DI scopes. I'll share the code from my activity and consumer implementations and maybe there is something missing in the activity one. I have tried to only keep the important part so if there is illegal syntax somewhere it's from me trying to clean up the code for SO.

Is this me using DI in a wrong way or something thats bugged with DI for activities? I tried following the "Scoped Filters" documentation on masstransits website. I'm on .net core 3.1 and masstransit 7.0.4.

**Scoped service used for testing**

```
//Interface
public interface IContextService
{
    string TenantId { get; set; }       
}
//DI registration
services.AddScoped<IContextService, ContextService>();
```

**Activity configuration, this is not working**

```
//Filter
public class RetreiveContextExecuteFilter<TArguments> : IFilter<ExecuteContext<TArguments>>
       where TArguments : class
    {
        public IContextService _contextService { get; }

        public RetreiveContextExecuteFilter(IContextService contextService)
        {
            _contextService = contextService;
        }

        public async Task Send(ExecuteContext<TArguments> context, IPipe<ExecuteContext<TArguments>> next)
        {
            _contextService.tenantId = "test-tenant";

            await next.Send(context);
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
            var scope = context.CreateFilterScope("testcontextinformation");
        }
    }

//Activity
public class ExampleActivity
    : IExecuteActivity<ExampleActivityArguments>
    {
        private readonly IContextService _contextService;

        public ExampleActivity(IContextService contextService)
        {
            _contextService = contextService;
        }

        public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<ExampleActivityArguments> context)
        {
            var tenant = _contextService.tenantId; //Empty
        }
    }

//DI
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
    {
    cfg.AddActivitiesFromNamespaceContaining<ExampleActivity>();
    services.TryAddSingleton(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);                       
    cfg.UsingRabbitMq(ConfigureBus);
});

private static void ConfigureBus(IBusRegistrationContext context, IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
{
    configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    configurator.UseExecuteActivityFilter(typeof(RetreiveContextExecuteFilter<>), context);
}
```

**Consumer configuration, this is working**

```
//Filter definition
public class RetreiveContextConsumeFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public IContextService _contextService { get; }

    public RetreiveContextConsumeFilter(IContextService contextService)
    {
        _contextService = contextService;
    }

    public Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        _contextService.TenantId = "test tenant";
        return next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateFilterScope("contextinformation");
    }
}

//Consumer
public class ExampleConsumer
: IConsumer<ExampleEvent>
{
    private readonly IContextService _contextService;

    public ExampleConsumer(IContextService contextService)
    {
        _contextService = contextService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ExampleEvent> context)
    {
         var id = _contextService.TenantId(); //Correct value
    }
}
//DI
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{              
    cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ExampleConsumer>();                 
    services.TryAddSingleton(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);                                    
    cfg.UsingRabbitMq(ConfigureBus);
});

private static void ConfigureBus(IBusRegistrationContext context, IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
{
    configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    configurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(RetreiveContextConsumeFilter<>), context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First guess, is that your configuration order is incorrect. MassTransit builds pipelines, and you are configuring your endpoints before the filter, which is going to make the filter run *after* the endpoints. That's my guess.

Change the consumer to:

```
configurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(RetreiveContextConsumeFilter<>), context);
configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
```

Change the activity to:

```
configurator.UseExecuteActivityFilter(typeof(RetreiveContextExecuteFilter<>), context);
configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
```

Comment: I have tried both versions and reversing it didn't help, it might fix other scenaris but not here. To make it simpler for you to see I made a minimal repo showing the problem. It might be easier to see what I have missed when I have isolated everything.
[GithubExample](https://github.com/filipmhpersson/MassTransitScopedTests/tree/master/MassTransitLab2) .

In the example I have the filters configured before the endpoints. As shown in the example, the Consumer can get tenant id set in the filter but the activity can't.

Comment: If I add `configurator.UseServiceScope` to my github example, before the other filters the scope seems to work correctly. Is that some bad hack or could it be needed for executeactivityfilters?

This is the end results for configuration if I do that, the code is to long to link here so I created a branch in the test repo to show it [UseServiceScope-branch](https://github.com/filipmhpersson/MassTransitScopedTests/blob/with-service-scope/MassTransitLab2/Program.cs).

Comment: UseServiceScope is a fine solution, if that solves your issue. I'm not sure why it is different for activities but will take a look at your example.